# How to resolve : more than one library with the package name com.google.android.gms in gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to resolve this error while compiling google play service gcm and admob.

Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
>   You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>   However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0[enter image description here][1]

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably vanish if you use the same version on both (7.8.0)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0' // <- remove this line
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

There is already 8.1+ though.

Also:
Gcm is already in the play services, you can remove the whole line.

Comment: Did that but getting Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2